# The sum of the values of the character of a given group representation

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory, lie-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group, $\rho: G \rightarrow GL(V)$ a finite dimensional representation over $\mathbb{C}$, and $\chi = tr(\rho)$ be the character of $\rho$.

Recall that since $G$ is finite, $|\chi(g)| \leq \dim(V)$ for any $g\in G$. While

$$
\Sigma_{g\in G} |\chi(g)| \leq |G|\dim(V),
$$

I feel that there might be a cancelling phenomenon in $\Sigma_{g\in G} \chi(g)$ when $\rho$ is not trivial.

#### Question

1. To what extent do the $\chi(g)$ cancel each other?
2. Can we say anything about the sum?
3. Can we generalize the result to any compact (or say unimodular) Lie group?

Comment: Doesn't your statement that $|\chi(g)| = 1$ for any $g \in G$ fail automatically if we take a two dimensional representation of $D_8$, the dihedral group of order $8$, say?

Comment: Sorry.. you are right. I meant $|\chi(g)| \leq \dim(V)$

Comment: Do you care about the sum over the character, or over the modulus of the character?

Comment: just over the character

Comment: Hint: Have you tried using the inner product?

Comment: Ah! No wonder they usually cancel out! Thank you so much. How about the 1-norm of $\chi$? (The 2-norm should just be $|G|$ by the trick of inner product.)